# Loading a texture image to a plane (Context Lost)

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to load a simple image as a texture to a plane in `react-three-fiber`. Here's a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-goldwasser-62yvw?file=/src/App.js) to the code-sandbox.

When I run this locally I get this message in the console:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.
```

CodeSandbox gives me nothing.

I have checked many examples from the internets and they all seem to do the same thing, but it works for them.

I'd appreciate some help with this.

Comment: The code sandbox runs fine on my computer (iMac) with latest Chrome. Can you please share some information about your system?

Comment: I managed to make it work using `Suspense` but I can't seem to convince the plane to display the image on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `MeshPhongMaterial`, the texture will only be visible if you add lights to your scene. However, you can also fix the issue by using the unlit `MeshBasicMaterial`.

Updated Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-kalam-p9lyq

Comment: small correction, the `{texture &&` isn't needed, texture is guaranteed to be there, otherwise the component would bail out (catch fetch errors with error-boundaries) :-)